# Slow access to HID top-level collection

Tags: c++, windows, collections, driver, hid

### Brief Description:

- My HID Device holds many top-level collections.
- Application constantly queries for collection details.
- Bottleneck is -  SetupDiGetClassDevs() seems to be very slow.

### Detailed Description:

My code basically follows [MS recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to find and obtain a handle to a HID collection. Then, I use this handle to obtain the corresponding preparsed data from which I get the data I need.

Currently, my code does this every time the user needs to obtain data (e.g. number of buttons, Axis min/max). This is a slow business. The profiler clearly says that the main culprit is **SetupDiGetClassDevs()** which seems to be very slow.

It is impossible to save the handle (Or so I think) as it may block the system from making changes such as removing the device or rearranging the devices. I still need to see what happens if I hold the top-level handle open for the entire session.

Another option I am contemplating is to save the preparsed data. MS implores us to release it by calling to HidD_FreePreparsedData(). What happens if we don't?

The last thing I was thinking of was to speed-up SetupDiGetClassDevs(). My current usage is:

```
HDEVINFO hardwareDeviceInfo = 
  SetupDiGetClassDevs ( 
     &HidGuid,
     NULL, // Define no enumerator (global)
      NULL, // Define no
      (DIGCF_PRESENT | // Only Devices present
      DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE)); // Function class devices.
```

Will it be sped up if I changed the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Simply release the preparsed data once you are done with the device. If the device is removed, a read or write to it will fail, and you can detect that by looking at the error code by calling `GetLastError()`